# Programming an Artificial Agent in Open Arena

Tags: ai, quake3

Does anyone know source example source codes and tutorials to start writing an intelligent bot for Open Arena?

Comment: It's good practice with this site to do your own search first, and include what you may have already found.

Comment: An _artificial_ bot?!

Answer (score 1):

Actual tutorials on the specific subject are sparse, but I did find a paper on a specific bot:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/20585341/The-Quake-III-Arena-Bot

As well as a list of commands for a quake 3 bot:
http://www.quake3world.com/q3guide/bots.html

The basic AI could be very simple, just a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) with states for:

- hunting other bots or players
- Fighting target
- running from other bots or players when low on resources
- looking for resources when low and not engaged

Writing the logic for each state, and the entrances and exits to each is where it can go from simple "fire gun at target" to complex "aim at target at rate X while moving to cover at position Y and fire once reticule is within Z of target".

Answer (score -1):

Quake 3 source code and UDK are the best examples.