# Quake 3 Bot Programming Example

Tags: ai, bot, quake3

I would like to implement an intelligent bot for Quake-3. I downloaded the and built the code successfully under Linux. My problem is that I couldn't find any complete tutorial telling me how to build an agent; telling which files to use( as there are many files in the source code).

Can you give me a website or piece of source code telling me how to start? Or something like an example source code for a bot.

Comment: I think your best bet will be to start a thread about this at the Quake3World.com programming forums, where several knowledgeable modders still reside. http://quake3world.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=16&sid=c7f5cc69fc3ee1e7c14a243400c32caa

Comment: This question is a little better formatted but the same as your previous question here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29408/programming-an-artificial-bot-in-open-arena

Comment: Consider editing your previous question instead of creating a new one.